# Is it possible to add a proxy setting for NPM on a per repo basis?

Tags: git, npm, proxy

I am working on one project, that requires proxy to use NPM. I don't want to set this globally, since this will affect other projects.

Is it possible to set this for only this one project? This would also help the onboarding of other programmers.

Comment: Aren't these settings local by default? When you run `npm config set` it sets the value in the local `package.json`. For global settings you need `npm config set --global`.

Comment: @phd sorry, but this doesnt add the proxy to the repo's `package.json`. I need to set the http, https and the no proxy values. =\